# I cannot make the headers of my gridview click able for sorting

Tags: asp.net, html, css, sorting, gridview

I have a gridview that I populate based on a query to a db. I'm trying to add sorting on my gridview but I cannot make my column headers clickable. I have allow sorting set to true, and I have my OnSorting event set. My columns are of a few different types. I know the code I need to have in my code behind, but I cannot click on the headers for some reason. Any help on what I'm missing would be appreciated.

```
<asp:GridView ID="Grid1" runat="server"  
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        OnSelectedIndexChanging="Selected_Row_Changing"
        DataKeyNames="ApplicationId"
        AllowPaging="True"
        OnPageIndexChanging="Grid1_PageIndexChanging"
        AllowSorting="True"
        OnSorting="Grid1_Sorting" 
        OnRowCreated="OnRowCreated"
        OnRowCommand="Grid1_RowCommand"
        OnRowDataBound="Grid1_RowDataBound">

        <Columns>
            <asp:templatefield ...>
                <itemtemplate>
                    <asp:linkbutton .../>
                </itemtemplate>
            </asp:templatefield>

            <asp:BoundField ... />

            <asp:HyperLinkField ... />

            <asp:ButtonField ...  />

        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have set the [SortExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sortexpression.aspx), have you?

For example:

```
<asp:boundfield datafield="CompanyName"
     headertext="CompanyName"
     headerstyle-wrap="false"
     sortexpression="CompanyName"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not setting the Header Template but rather set the HeaderText attribute for the TemplateField